# Sql select 2 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

[image: Union ALL for two tables]
[image]

The first image is my MySQL query result.
I want to get just like the second image.
Please help.

This is my MySQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
      PPUser.[UserID] AS'UserID',
      PPUser.[UserName] AS 'Name',
      NULL AS 'RO',
      NULL AS 'RO_UserID'
FROM [RF_ROTeacher]
LEFT JOIN PPUser ON RF_ROTeacher.UserID = PPUser.PUID
UNION ALL
SELECT 
      NULL AS 'UserID',
      NULL AS 'Name',
      PPUser.[UserID] AS 'RO',
      PPUser.[UserName] AS 'RO_UserID'
FROM [RF_ROTeacher]
LEFT JOIN PPUser ON RF_ROTeacher.ROID = PPUser.PUID
)A
```

Thanks all.

Comment: Could you provide sample data for `RF_ROTeacher` and `PPUser`?

Comment: You are clearly **not** using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need two different queries. Try this instead

```
SELECT p.[UserID]   AS'UserID',
       p.[UserName] AS'Name',
       f.[UserID]   AS 'RO',
       f.[UserName] AS 'RO_UserID'
FROM   [RF_ROTeacher]
       LEFT JOIN PPUser f
              ON RF_ROTeacher.ROID = f.PUID
       LEFT JOIN PPUser p
              ON RF_ROTeacher.UserID = p.PUID
```

Comment: Because the values of the UserID and RO are now the same which should not be.

Answer (score 0):

You may also try this query to get your desired result:

```
SELECT UserID,Name,RO,RO_UserID FROM
(SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PPUser) AS row1,
      PPUser.[UserID] AS 'UserID',
      PPUser.[UserName] AS 'Name'
FROM [RF_ROTeacher]) A 

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PPUser) AS row2,
      PPUser.[UserID] AS 'RO',
      PPUser.[UserName] AS 'RO_UserID'
FROM [RF_ROTeacher])B
ON A.row1=B.row2
```